# Willie Bot Job() and JobSchedular() AttributeError

Tags: python, bots, irc

Trying to use Willie's job scheduler to `bot.say('Hello world!')` once every 2 seconds...don't know if I am doing something wrong or if the `Job()` and `JobSchedular()` aren't meant to be public api's.

http://willie.dftba.net/docs/#willie.bot.Willie.JobScheduler

I get `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'thread'` from `bob.run()`:

```
def dunno(bot):
    bot.say('Hello, world!')

@willie.module.commands('try')
def run_it(bot, trigger):
    bot.say('trying')
    jobb = bot.Job(2, dunno)
    bob = bot.JobScheduler(bot)
    bob.add_job(jobb)
    bob.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct tool to use is Willie's [interval](http://willie.dftba.net/docs/#the-willie-class).